# Just switched to Ubuntu, fn keys dont work

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have an ASUS ROG GU501 and it has a function tied to almost every F key using fn + key. I use all of them pretty regularly and so i would like to keep that functionality. However, I do not know how to do it since I am a complete noob to linux. 

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> = mute

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> = track back (last item in music player)

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> = play/pause

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> = track forward

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> = fan control

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> = turn off display

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> = dim

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f8</kbd> = brighten

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> = presentation mode

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> = disable trackpad

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> = sleep

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> = airplane mode

i know these probably seem like stupid, or menial things, but I use them pretty regularly as well as just about any key shortcut out there, so i dont want to map them using alt or anything, and when i try to map them using the fn key it just doesnt recognize the fn key.

Comment: Does pressing F1 without using FN mute?

Comment: no, opens a new tab in opera

Comment: Your are missing one fn + ESC switches Fn mode ;) one extra thing: the Fn keys are NOT connected to the OS but connected to your hardware. edit: oops this is old :D